# What is the best way to determine if there are any GameObjects inside a certain area

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in which I know would want to embed grenades. What would be the best way to find all game objects within a certain radius from the grenade before it explodes? I have already seen that one way is too have all enemies/opponents in an array and then loop through the array to see how many would be within a certain area but I was wondering if there would be a better way to approach this.

Edit:

Hello, please if you see this, vote this question up for some reason I was banned for a fine question which only got 1-. (most likely because it was my first question so my account was very susceptible to being banned) It originally said it was only a 1 day ban but apparently not as it has been two days already....

Comment: If all relevant objects have colliders, you can retrieve them with [`Physics.OverlapSphere()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html).

Comment: what if they are not overlapping with the box collider of the grenade though? Serlite

Comment: That's not how `OverlapSphere()` works - you specify a position (probably where your grenade is) and a radius, and it checks for all colliders within that spherical area.

Comment: Happy to help out! I've put all the information together into a proper answer - if you're satisfied with it, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it and your question will be marked as solved. (Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the objects you want to detect have colliders attached to them, you can use [`Physics.OverlapSphere()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html). Just supply it a position and a radius to retrieve all colliders within a spherical area:

```
Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(grenadePosition, explosionRadius);
```

Then you can loop through them and apply damage as needed. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is way better than my approach... didn't know about this until I had to use it in my own game and searched for a specific function which does that. Ended up using the Physics.OverlapSphere function.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to approach this is, as you already said, to have the objects in an array.
I would set the tag "Enemy" for the enemies and then loop through all gameobjects which are tagged with "Enemy".

```
foreach(GameObject gameObj in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy") {
     // check if the current gameObj is in a certain range of your grenade object
}
```